# Java + Spring + Vault: Chinese character in a password, became "???" in the app

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault

Small question regarding a Spring Boot 2.4.2 app, where I need to retrieve a password stored inside Vault, containing special/Chinese character please.

Setup:
A Hashicorp Vault instance which is storing our passwords. So far so good, for most of the passwords, it is storing them safely, and we can retrieve them, very happy.

Once the password is retrieved by the app, it is used to make an http request to some third party API. The third party API gives us the password via other channel and we store it inside Vault (question is not here)

We retrieve the password via this way, with the Spring Vault library.

```
    @Value("${password.from.vault}")
    private String               passwordFromVault;
```

And use it this way to make the http call

```
webClient.mutate().baseUrl("https://third-party").build().get().uri("/uri").header("X-the-password", passwordFromVault ).[...]
```

When the password inside Vault is plain English letter, this is working fine.

Now, for some of the passwords we see them with special Chinese character

```
$ vault kv get secret/creds
====== Data ======
Key         Value
---         -----
password.from.vault    password-新年快乐-password
```

Unfortunately, this seems to cause issues.
The API call started to fail, and after a quick debug session, the third party assured us they see this from their logs

```
X-the-password: password-????-password
```

Basically claiming, we are not sending the correct password (the one with special/Chinese character)

I have tried this thinking it was an encoding issue, but not working neither

```
final String  pleaseHelp   = new String(passwordFromVault.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
webClient.mutate().baseUrl("https://third-party").build().get().uri("/uri").header("X-the-password", pleaseHelp ).[...]
```

Question, How can I retrieve and send the request so the third party API gets the correct password containing special characters please?

Thank you

Comment: "`new String(passwordFromVault.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`" is almost certainly not what you intend. If `passwordFromVault` contains codepoints outside the 0-255 range, `passwordFromVault.getBytes(ISO_8859_1)` will replace those codepoints with a `?`-like character. [Demo](https://ideone.com/Tk3jyS)

Comment: agree, which is why I am asking the question. I understand I am not doing things correctly. I just do not know what is the correct solution (hence the question)

Comment: and also ".header("X-the-password", passwordFromVault )" is not working neither

Comment: Have you tried something like

    webClient.baseUrl("https://third-party").build().get().uri("/uri").header("X-the- 
    password").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).retrieve();

or with deprecated MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8

Comment: Just tried, same issue, unfortunately. But many thanks for the answer. I believe it is something related to how Vault is storing it in the first place, and how the app is retrieving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those escaped ascii characters (for instance 新年快乐), if they are inserted from the web UI, are automatically inserted as 新年快乐.

In order to get them at run time, they should be inserted with the vault cli, as `\u5317\u4eac` for instance